# How play a video from a Stream in Visual Basic 6

Tags: video, vb6, stream, video-streaming

I know that VB6 is a very old compiler, but i need to know how can play a video from a stream?
Any component or solution will be great!

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Windows Media Player component is preferred!

Comment: It depends on the type of stream. As said, most standard (RTSP/Mpeg/AVI over RTSP/HTTP, but not FLV, etc) are supported by the media player components. You can't easily use DirechShow itself from VB6 though. Any other formats may require decoding and displaying yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

google for the use of the quartz.dll. its part of windows.

its a german page, but maybe helpful:

http://www.vbarchiv.net/forum/read.php?id=2&t=100680&i=100680&v=t